# How do you write a mysqldump command to prevent the dump from changing a string to integer?

Tags: mysql

I'm using the Make theme from ThemeFoundry for a WordPress site and there is a reported bug during migration that can change the "s" for string to "i" for integer when dumping the to a bak.sql file.

My command is the general:

mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] -h [localhost] --add-drop-table [databasename] > bak.sql

What would I add in the command to prevent the dump from changing the "i" for integer to "s" from string.

Here is how it reads now:

```
(258,58,'_ttfmake-section-ids','a:5:{i:0;i:1421763871966;i:1;i:1416065912111;i:2;i:1419892730240;i:3;i:1421655348319;i:4;i:1422390643025;}')
```

I believe it should be i:0;s:1421763871966;

Comment: From mysqldumps prospective, this is just one text string (VARCHAR). It would never alter the string during the dump. If it's "i:0;i" in the dump output – it's "i:0;i" in your database. So, basically, this question has no answer because mysqldump doesn't change types :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Something happened on import where the "s" was changed to an "i" on import. Don't know how that happened. It's an issue with Theme Foundry theme called Make.

Here's the original post: https://thethemefoundry.com/questions/topic/builder-modules-have-disappeared-in-edit-screen/